# Selenium, selecting from dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

there is a dropdown on a website. I want to select EUR.

I tried all kind of methods (python+selenium) i could find on the internet, nothing works for my specific case :(

For example

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(by.class, ....))
select.select_by_visible_text('...')
```

Also tried xpath, getting the following error: imgur.com/a/DYfA4UI

Website is: funpay.com/en
xpath: '//*[@id="navbar"]/ul[2]/li[4]/ul/li/a'

Anyone able to help?

This is how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9wDu.jpg

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try with "CSS seletor" to localize the dropdown with google developer tools and use something like this :

```
menu = dropdown.find_element_by_css_selector("#li.dropdown")
menu.click()
options = menu.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
for option in options:
    if option.text == 'EUR':
        eur = option
```

Comment: Already tried it too.

Getting the following error: https://imgur.com/a/DYfA4UI

Website is: https://funpay.com/en/

xpath: '//*[@id="navbar"]/ul[2]/li[4]/ul/li/a'

Comment: Try again with what i will post in this answer

Comment: I post new answer

Comment: It worked. I only had to "click" the dropdown first. Only then, the option EUR was visible.

Comment: Ok, i will fix it here