# How do I use the Selenium Click function

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a login button after filling out all the information for the website. So far I have been able to fill in spaces using `driver.find_element("id","username").send_keys("username")` when I use `driver.find_element_id("username").send_keys("username")` it wont work.

The login button elements are class=radius and type=sumbit also i class="fa fa-2x fa-sign-in"
(I would just link the site but I dont know if that would be against TOS)

So far I have used the following commands
`element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login")`
`element.click()`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="login"]/button.click()` but xpath gives an "unresolved reference"

I am using IDE PyCharm Build #PC-222.4167.33 on Windows

Comment: What is the Selenium version you are using?

Comment: @AbiSaran 4.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("<enter the username>")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("<enter the password>")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".radius").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button.secondary.radius").click()
time.sleep(2)
```

I have added '`time.sleep()`' just to show you it is working correctly, avoid using it in your real-time projects.

Comment: @AbriSaran I am trying to click the login button with the following ```login = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Login")``` ```login.click()``` but its not working

Comment: Can you post the URL or page source of the URL?

Comment: http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login

Comment: Okay that works. I also took a look again at XPATH function and I had to use the full xpath not just the xpath. So ```driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/button").click()``` worked as well. Thank you.

Comment: @AbriSaran I am working on my actual project and using all the information in this thread I am still unable to get the button to work. The website it behind certs so I can only give you the elements I made on my github, sorry about that. https://github.com/redswamii/Selenium-Automation/blob/main/bad%20source%20code

Comment: Try using all the locator types, ID, XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, etc., If the Button's property is dynamically changing, try XPATH with 'contains()' or 'starts-with()', it should work. Practice how to write relative XPATH, don't use absolute XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem I solve here [Selenium, selecting from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981888/selenium-selecting-from-dropdown/73981989?noredirect=1#comment130697788_73981989)

You should localize the element with XPath or CSS selector, i recommend you try with CSS selector, if don't work try with xpath .

Comment: could you show the page  and the exactly button ?